# Where is the error traceback message for unhandled exceptions written - sys.stdout or sys.stderr or somewhere else? (in Python)

Tags: python, stdout, stderr, unhandled-exception, traceback

As per my understanding, in Python, `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` are the file objects linked to the standard input, output and error streams respectively. Now the `stdout` and `stderr` file objects can be changed to arbitrary files in order to log them somewhere else apart from the console.

I did this, and everything worked fine. However, I noticed that in case of unhandled exceptions, an error traceback message is thrown which was being displayed in the console. That indicates that this traceback message was not directed to `stdout` or `stderr`.

Please find below the code that was run:

```
import sys

old_stdout, old_stderr = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
sys.stdout, sys.stderr = open('Outfile.txt', 'w'), open('Errorlog.txt', 'w')

try:
    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    print('Hi %s' % name)
    age = int(input('What is your age? '))
    if age <= 0:
        raise ValueError('Age cannot be 0.')
    else:
        print('So how does it feel to be %d' % age)
# except Exception as e:
#     print(e)
finally:
    sys.stderr.close(), sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stderr, sys.stdout = old_stderr, old_stdout
```

When the except block is present, the error message is getting printed as per expectation in stdout (i.e., `Outfile.txt`). When the `except` block is commented out to make it an unhandled exception, the traceback is getting printed in the console as below:

```
F:\> python.exe Change_stdout_stderr_to_log_files.py
Anirban
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Change_stdout_stderr_to_log_files.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise ValueError('Age cannot be 0.')
ValueError: Age cannot be 0.

F:\>
```

Nothing is printed regarding the error in stdout or stderr though. So where is this error message actually directed?

Comment: This behavior is generally a good idea. Just as you can't safely log a kernel panic in the I/O subsystem to disk without risking corrupting your file system -- if the local Python interpreter is broken enough that you have exceptions that application-layer logic couldn't handle, it's wise to assume that trying to log the exception through a runtime that's known to be in a state that the running application's developers didn't anticipate would fail too.

Comment: Note that overriding `sys.stderr` doesn't override file descriptor #2, which remains accessible.

Comment: Just to check my understanding of the above (2nd) comment by @Charles Duffy - _"doesn't override file descriptor #2"_ does it denote that - file descriptor #2 is python interpreter's own stderr file object which remains unaffected. The traceback message is printed to the python interpreter's stderr file object.

Comment: I wouldn't even use the word "object" -- the FD table is the kernel's map from numbered identifiers to (kernel space) file handles. Python file objects may have file descriptors behind them used to write to actual OS-level files, but file descriptors can exist (and be used) without there being any Python file object behind them at all. See `os.write` as a way to write to such FDs.

Comment: ...so, if you override `sys.stderr`, that won't change where `os.write(2, 'hello\n')` goes to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have redirected *your program's* standard error to somewhere else, but *Python's* standard error is still connected to your terminal.

Observe:

```
bash$ python -c 'import sys; sys.stderr = open("/dev/null"); raise ValueError("I am the walrus")'
bash$ python -c '=' 2>/dev/null
bash$ python -c 'import sys; sys.stderr = open("/dev/null"); raise ValueError("I am the walrus"); ='
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; sys.stderr = open("/dev/null"); raise ValueError("I am the walrus"); =
                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```